# Jquery removeAttr and add Attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, checked, prop

I am trying to do something very simple. I have 10 input fields and one of these has the checked attribute. I want to remove this attribute and apply it to another known input field.

My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.article-vote').removeAttr('checked');
    $('input#rating' + id).attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

As can be seen I am remove the attribute by class and selecting the target by id.

When I run this code the checked attribute is removed but the target isn't applied. If I remove the removeAttr line then the target has the attribute applied.

How can I remove all and apply to a target of my choice?

Comment: use `.prop("checked",true|false)` instead of removing and adding because it is a property anyway and not an attribute

Comment: @guradio is 'attr' an outdated implementation of jQuery? Thanks for the info regarding trye false rather than removal.

Comment: Consider reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to remove the `checked` attribute, but rather set it to true or false.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.article-vote').prop('checked', false);
  $('input#rating' + id).prop('checked', true);
});
```